# Logger Library for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

Is there any good logger library for iOS development like log4J in Java?

I found log4cocoa. But its not updated in years now.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799050/is-there-a-logging-framework-log4j-style-for-objective-c

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have not checked them all, but may be this helps:

[Flexible iOS Logging](http://brenwill.com/2010/flexible-ios-logging/)

[NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger)

[SOSmax](http://labs.grupow.com/index.php/2010/12/objective-c-logging-with-sosmax/)

[GTMLogger (google-toolbox-for-mac)](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMLogger.h)

[ASLogger](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/master/ASLogger/)

[cola-framework](http://code.google.com/p/cola-framework/)

[Cocoa Lumberjac](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack)

Comment: CocoaLumberjack do not use code.google.com. new link https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack

Answer (score 5):

I've used https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack with much success.  Its an easy, drop in replacement for NSLog and allows you to change log levels.  I did struggle with setting up a global log level (as opposed to per file) and changing log levels at runtime as that wasn't well documented.  Its been a while, though, so perhaps that's been improved.  Nonetheless, it produced excellent log files that I was able to use for troubleshooting in the wild.